# How do I call viewDidLoad Manually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, protocols, viewdidload

I'm having a slight problem with iOS. I am passing data back and forth between two view controllers using protocols and manually switching views. My problem is that when I dismiss the top view, viewDidLoad for the bottom view isn't called again. Since I'm sending information from my second view to my first view, I need viewDidLoad to be called so I can handle the information I'm passing. If you have any ideas on how to do this, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Another possible solution is to have both views controllers share the same model, but I'm unsure how to do that either.

Comment: Move your logic out of viewDidLoad. You're not supposed to call it. A better place might be viewDidAppear:, but actually since you already have a protocol in place for communication, the best place is to use that protocol to convey that something changed. The first view will then be responsible for updating itself when it receives that protocol message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Also one last thing, my protocol is returning a null value when I call a function. Are there any common reasons for this?

Comment: @Adam please post some code (maybe another question). it's hard to say with this info

Answer (score 9):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Is called exactly once, when the view controller is first loaded into memory. This is where you want to instantiate any instance variables and build any views that live for the entire lifecycle of this view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Is called when the view is actually visible, and can be called multiple times during the lifecycle of a View Controller (example when a Modal View Controller is dismissed and the view becomes visible again)

Answer (score 0):

> I am passing data back and forth between two view controllers using protocols and manually switching views. My problem is that when I dismiss the top view, viewDidLoad for the bottom view isn't called again. Since I'm sending information from my second view to my first view, I need viewDidLoad to be called

No you don't, and the fact that you think you do makes me think something else may be going wrong here.

Consider this: if you are truly passing data back from the second view controller from the first, then the first view controller *has* the data and can update itself *now*. It exists, and it has a view. So it should update itself on the spot, as you hand it the data. Then, when you dismiss the second view controller, the first view controller's view will appear - already updated. In effect, dismissing the second view controller merely *reveals* the first view controller's view, which was there all along, and was updated even though it wasn't showing.

Comment: Well the thing is that I need a place to "handle" the data that's being passed back. Say for example I pass it an array of strings and I want to do something with it, like pass it to the model for instance. How would I do it if not in viewDidLoad? A touch event is called to place the view in the foreground. Could I handle it in this touch event, right after I call to present the second view?

Comment: If you are truly passing back data, you are doing it by calling a method on the first view controller. So now the first view controller is in action! It receives the array of strings in some method and can do whatever it is, right there in that method.

Comment: Well it's like this. My touch event calls a view to be placed on my first. Then which I click a button on the second view, That sets a certain piece of data. When the second view is dismissed I want that data passed back.

Comment: So pass it back. Pass it back in the second view's `viewWillDisappear:`, for example. That way, the first view has it, and, as I said, has updated its appearance, before the first view is revealed by the disappearance of the second view.